# comscore api and implementation related

Tags: javascript, php, seo, comscore

A friend of mine is planning to implement comscore for tracking his site and I'm helping him do that. Went through a pdf doc that described the variables c1,c2...their purpose, if required or not etc. My question is regarding the code implementation.
The code creates a script element and appends the src value and places it in the body tag.
There's no specific reason mentioned as to why it's in the form of inserting it into the DOM structure rather than merely placing the chunk of code in beginning or end respectively.
Also if possible please let me know if any of you uses comscore for tracking your site analytics and if its better than Omniture Site Catalyst..if so in what way.
Thanks in advance,
Optimus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a script tag and adding it to the DOM is essentially asynchronously loading the comscore script.

If you add it to your head, it will block all further loading until the comscore script itself is downloaded and executed.

If you add it to the end, you will delay the DOM ready event which may delay the execution of scripts waiting for that event.

In short, it's better for your load times to create the script tag and add it to the DOM. Even better is to not do this until after the load event.

More on that topic: http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/why-loading-third-party-scripts-async-is-not-good-enough

Comment: good answer and nice reference... makes a lot of sense now...truly didn't expect an answer after 7 months :)